# Error connecting to web server: Module not found: Can't resolve './RCTNetworking'

Tags: react-native, expo, apollo-client

Failed to compile.
/Users/mohdjabiuddin/MNCL.DEV/MY-PROJECTS/renter-graphql/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './RCTNetworking' in '/Users/jabiuddin/MNCL.DEV/MY-PROJECTS/renter-graphql/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'

Comment: Hello there :) Please add more details to your question. You should add what you are doing, what you are trying to achieve and the precise error you are getting. You should also add code snippets or at least screenshots of your errors from the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a problem with `reactotron`, I had the same problem with Ignite boilderplate from Infinite Red.
If so, you should install reactotron version for web.

### Fast solution

Install `reactotron-react-js` and import it instead of `reactotron-react-native`:

```
yarn add -D reactotron-react-js
```

```js
// import Tron from "reactotron-react-native"
import Tron from "reactotron-react-js"
```

### Long term solution

Install `reactotron-react-js`:

```
yarn add -D reactotron-react-js
```

Add separate configuration for `web` and `native`

```js
// reactotron.native.ts
import Tron from "reactotron-react-native"
...
```

```js
// reactotron.web.ts
import Tron from "reactotron-react-js"
...
```

Thanks to metro bundle this configuration will be loaded depend on environment. Maybe you have to comment some other configuration (depends on Ignite version).

Comment: I have no idea how you diagnosed that question, but this solved my problem. :) Perhaps I need to set something in Metro to better handle platform-specific files with the `.native` part, but I got this working by leaving my RN file as `reactotron.js` and naming the new one `reactotron.web.js`.